# Deleting file contents android

Tags: java, android, file-io, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I need to delete the contents of a file, before I write more information into it. I've tried different ways, such as where I delete the content but the file stays the same size, and when I start writing in it after the deletion, a blank hole appears to be the size of the deletion before my new data is written.

This is what I've tried...

```
BufferedWriter bw;
try {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
    bw.write("");
    bw.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I've also tried this...

```
File f = new File(file);
FileWriter fw;

try {
    fw = new FileWriter(f,false);
    fw.write("");
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can someone please help me with a solution to this problem.

Comment: Can't you just delete the file and create a new empty one?

Comment: No, I need to be the same file but thanks for your answer

Answer (score 8):

```
FileWriter (path, false)
```

The false will tell the writer to truncate the file instead of appending to it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want because I want to clear the contents of the file.

Comment: Sorry, didnt see the false in the second piece of code there.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `flush()` before calling `close()`.

```
FileWriter writer = null;

try {
   writer = ... // initialize a writer
   writer.write("");
   writer.flush(); // flush the stream
} catch (IOException e) {
   // do something with exception
} finally {
   if (writer != null) {
      writer.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it still is the same. I do not understand. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you are not closing the FileWriter, fw.close(); also you dont need to "delete" the old data, just start writing and it will overwrite the old data. So make sure you are closing everywhere.

This works for me:

```
    File f=new File(file);
    FileWriter fw;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(f);
        fw.write("");
       fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```